# jitsi video conference call

Tags: java, android, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I created Jitsi meet video conference call using android studio and java. How can I get the information of how long this conference people hold

```
private void sendRemoteMessage(String remoteMessageBody, String type) {
        ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class).sendRemoteMessage(
                Constants.getRemoteMessageHeader(), remoteMessageBody
        ).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (type.equals(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_ACCEPTED)) {
                        //Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, "Davet Kabul Edildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        try {

                            URL serverURL = new URL("https://meet.jit.si");
                            JitsiMeetConferenceOptions conferenceOptions =
                                    new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                                            .setServerURL(serverURL)
                                            .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                                            .setRoom(getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_MEETING_ROOM))
                                            .build();


                            JitsiMeetActivity.launch(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, conferenceOptions);
                            finish();
                        } catch (Exception exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, "Davet Reddedildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.e("OutgoingInvitation", "Error sending remote message: " + t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver invitationResponseReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String type = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE);
            if (type != null) {
                if (type.equals(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_CANCELLED)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "invitation Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(
                invitationResponseReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE)
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(
                invitationResponseReceiver
        );
    }
```

I tried all the methods I could think of, but without success. I'm new to coding please help

My codes are as you can see. When the call button is pressed, two activities are opened simultaneously for the caller and the called person.

can you show me a way?
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.